# layout-parser basic api test code throws weird error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, layout-parser

I am trying out layout-parser api from

https://layout-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/modelzoo.html#example-usage

My detectron2 installation is quite successful as evident from running `python -m detectron2.utils.collect_env`

So is my torch installation by running `pip3 show torch`

I have created a first sample as below

```
import layoutparser as lp
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("data/test-image.jpeg")
image = image[..., ::-1]
model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel(
            config_path ='lp://PubLayNet/faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x/config', # In model catalog
            label_map   ={0: "Text", 1: "Title", 2: "List", 3:"Table", 4:"Figure"}, # In model`label_map`
            extra_config=["MODEL.ROI_HEADS.SCORE_THRESH_TEST", 0.8] # Optional
        )
model.detect(image)
```

Running the above with `python3 sample-first.py` throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/_dga/ml-git/layout-parser-trial/sample-first.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel(
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/layoutparser/models/layoutmodel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self._create_model()
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/layoutparser/models/layoutmodel.py", line 149, in _create_model
    self.model = self._engine.DefaultPredictor(self.cfg)
  File "/Users/_dga/ml-git/detectron2/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 288, in __init__
    checkpointer.load(cfg.MODEL.WEIGHTS)
  File "/Users/_dga/ml-git/detectron2/detectron2/checkpoint/detection_checkpoint.py", line 62, in load
    ret = super().load(path, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/fvcore/common/checkpoint.py", line 155, in load
    checkpoint = self._load_file(path)
  File "/Users/_dga/ml-git/detectron2/detectron2/checkpoint/detection_checkpoint.py", line 99, in _load_file
    loaded = self._torch_load(filename)
  File "/Users/_dga/ml-git/detectron2/detectron2/checkpoint/detection_checkpoint.py", line 114, in _torch_load
    return super()._load_file(f)
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/fvcore/common/checkpoint.py", line 252, in _load_file
    return torch.load(f, map_location=torch.device("cpu"))
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 815, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1033, in _legacy_load
    magic_number = pickle_module.load(f, **pickle_load_args)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

It seems to be coming from torch and I am guessing its unable to load the model in question.

I am using MAC M2 with python3.9  for the whole exercise.

After some research on chatgpt and google, I downgraded my detectron2 to 0.5 from 0.6 and have a new issue

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/_dga/ml-git/layout-parser-trial/sample-first.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = lp.models.Detectron2LayoutModel(
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/layoutparser/models/layoutmodel.py", line 52, in __new__
    cls._import_module()
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/layoutparser/models/layoutmodel.py", line 40, in _import_module
    cls, m["import_name"], importlib.import_module(m["module_path"])
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/engine/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .hooks import *
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/engine/hooks.py", line 19, in <module>
    from detectron2.evaluation.testing import flatten_results_dict
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/evaluation/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .cityscapes_evaluation import CityscapesInstanceEvaluator, CityscapesSemSegEvaluator
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/evaluation/cityscapes_evaluation.py", line 11, in <module>
    from detectron2.data import MetadataCatalog
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/data/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import transforms  # isort:skip
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/data/transforms/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .transform import *
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/data/transforms/transform.py", line 36, in <module>
    class ExtentTransform(Transform):
  File "/Users/_dga/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/detectron2/data/transforms/transform.py", line 46, in ExtentTransform
    def __init__(self, src_rect, output_size, interp=Image.LINEAR, fill=0):
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'LINEAR'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I tried your sample script, and no error !!!

**python -m detectron2.utils.collect_env**

```
-------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.platform                     win32
Python                           3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
numpy                            1.23.5
detectron2                       0.6 @c:\travail\stackoverflow\detectron2\detectron2
Compiler                         MSVC 193532217
CUDA compiler                    not available
DETECTRON2_ENV_MODULE            <not set>
PyTorch                          2.0.1+cpu @C:\Travail\Anaconda3\envs\chatgpt\lib\site-packages\torch
PyTorch debug build              False
torch._C._GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI  False
GPU available                    No: torch.cuda.is_available() == False
Pillow                           10.0.0
torchvision                      0.15.2+cpu @C:\Travail\Anaconda3\envs\chatgpt\lib\site-packages\torchvision
fvcore                           0.1.5.post20221221
iopath                           0.1.9
cv2                              4.8.0
```

detectron2 in version 0.5 uses LINEAR in PILLOW. But from version 10 of PILLOW, LINEAR is deprecated and replaced by BILINEAR, hence the problem you are having.

Th version detectron2==0.6 use BILINEAR, but 0.5 use LINEAR

Try to downgrade pillow from 10 to 9x

2. I change the model to use mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x instead of faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x, and ....

   UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.

i tried to pickle each of two models :

GOOD (faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x)

```
with open('.torch/iopath_cache\\s/dgy9c10wykk4lq4\\model_final.pth', 'rb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.load(pickle_file)
```

BAD (mask_rcnn_X_101_32x8d_FPN_3x)

```
with open('.torch/iopath_cache\\s/57zjbwv6gh3srry\\model_final.pth', 'rb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.load(pickle_file)




Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[25], line 2
    pickle.load(pickle_file)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '<'.
```

An article on https://github.com/ying09/TextFuseNet/issues/55 talks about issue when download the file.

Comment: yes. versions were an issue, I had to downgrade detectron2 as you have advised along with pillow to 9.5.0 instead of the latest 10. That solved the issues. But important note - I am finding the best model advised in layoutparser insufficient for modern newspaper content. Think I will need to devise a model from scratch.